# How to insert/update a list of data into mongodb using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, list, pymongo

have a collection with values:

name and age are unique values with compound index

```
{
_id:ObjectId(5db012b123a2a1cabcc12345),
name:"mark_102",
age:"38",
occupation:null,
date:2019-10-23T10:55:50.569+00:00
}


{
_id:ObjectId(5db012b123a2a1cabcc12346),
name:"sheldon_103",
age:"45",
occupation:null,
date:2019-10-23T10:55:50.569+00:00
}
```

have a list with data:

data_list:

```
[{'name': "mark_102",
  'age': "38",
  'occupation': "admin"},
 {'name': "sheldon_103",
  'age': "45",
  'occupation': "devs"}]
```

How to insert/update data into mongodb and change the occupation from null to mentioned values in `data_list`

tried this :

`mydb.test.insert_many(data_list)`
`mydb.test.update_many(data_list)`

Got this error:

`BulkWriteError: batch op errors occurred`

Comment: Hey, is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62035969/6635464) helpful?

Comment: I think you are looking for the [Update with Upsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#update-with-upsert).